# Bind DatePicker.IsEnabled to ComboBoxItem.IsSelected

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ComboBox with two options, as follows:

```
<ComboBox Name="TypeComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="TemporaryComboItem">Temporary</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="PermanentComboItem">Permanent</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In case the "Temporary" option is selected, I have a DatePicker to select the expiration date, as follows:

```
<DatePicker
    Name="ExpirationDatePicker"
    IsEnabled="{Binding TemporaryComboItem.IsSelected}" 
/>
```

However this `Binding` does not seem to work, as the DatePicker can be used regardless of the selected option.

**How can I have the DatePicker to be functional only when one of the options is selected?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly dirty solution:

```
<ComboBox Name="TypeComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="TemporaryComboItem" Tag="True">Temporary</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="PermanentComboItem" >Permanent</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<DatePicker Name="ExpirationDatePicker"
            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=TypeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Tag, FallbackValue=False}" />
```

Note how I set the Tag property for the Temporary item and changed the binding for the IsEnabled property. The binding now 'looks' at the combobox's selected item's Tag. If it is not there, it defaults to false.

This 'abuses' the Tag property. In general I would advise against that as it is not clear what the Tag property does/means.

A proper way might be by binding all these UI elements to ViewModels so the DatePicker could bind to a property on the ViewModel that more clearly expresses the meaning/use.